# Angular 2/4 loading scripts dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

In angular 2 one can load CSS styles depending on the component. However, there is no corresponding way to load script files. I am currently loading all scripts on the base page of my single page applications but that results in optimization issues.

What is the advised way of loading scripts for an Angular 2/4 component.

Comment: what scripts ?  scripts cannot be used with specific components it has to be in index.html

Comment: If you need to load third party JS scripts or libs try and embedd that in your application instead of using it in index.html here is a [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can load script dynamically in any component.

Here is the solution :

1. Create a service in which you'll have js file.

   ```
   // script.store.ts

   interface Scripts {
     name: string;
     src: string;
   }

   export const ScriptStore: Scripts[] = [
     { name: 'moment', src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js' },
     { name: 'datatables', src: 'https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.12/datatables.min.js' }
   ];
   ```
2. Now create a service that will load & return the status of the script.

   ```
   // script.service.ts

   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { ScriptStore } from './script.store';

   declare var document: any;
   declare var jQuery: any;

   @Injectable()
   export class Script {
     public scripts: any = {};

     load(...scripts: string[]) {
       var promises: any[] = [];
       scripts.forEach((script)=>promises.push(this.loadScript(script)));
       return Promise.all(promises);
     }

     loadScript(name: string) {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         //resolve if already loaded
         if (this.scripts[name].loaded) {
           resolve({script:name, loaded:true, status:'Already Loaded'});
         }
         else{
           //load script
           let script = document.createElement('script');
           script.type = 'text/javascript';
           script.src = this.scripts[name].src;
           if(script.readyState) {  //IE
             script.onreadystatechange = () => {
               if ( script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete" ) {
                 script.onreadystatechange = null;
                 this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
                 resolve({script:name, loaded:true, status:'Loaded'});
               }
             };
           } else {  //Others
             script.onload = () => {
               this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
               resolve({script:name, loaded:true, status:'Loaded'});
             };
           }
           script.onerror = (error: any) => resolve({script:name, loaded:false, status:'Loaded'});
           document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
         }
       });
     }

     constructor() {
       ScriptStore.forEach((script: any) => {
         this.scripts[script.name]={
           loaded: false,
           src: script.src
         };
       });
     }
   }
   ```
3. Now you just need to import & call the service.

   ```
   // import
   import {Script} from './script.service'; // specify the path where you have created the service

   // Now call service

   ngAfterViewInit() {
     this._script.load('datatables')
       .then((data:any )=>{
         console.log(data,'script loaded')
       })
       .catch((error)=>{
       });
   }
   ```

It will dynamically add the script of 'datatables'.

This only serves your purpose but also it will load only where it is necessary.

Comment: Do you have a working plnkr of this code? I've tried it and I get an error that it can't find _script.load.

Comment: Don't have the plnkr but I got you.It seems you haven't defined the script in the constructor.

Here is the example-

constructor(
      public _script: Script ) {
}

This will resolve your error.

Answer (score 1):

You can load **multiple scripts dynamically** like this in your `component.ts` file:

```
 loadScripts() {
    const dynamicScripts = [
     'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js',
     '../../../assets/js/dummyjs.min.js'
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < dynamicScripts.length; i++) {
      const node = document.createElement('script');
      node.src = dynamicScripts[i];
      node.type = 'text/javascript';
      node.async = false;
      node.charset = 'utf-8';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
    }
  }
```

and call this method inside the constructor,

```
constructor() {
    this.loadScripts();
}
```

Note : For more scripts to be loaded dynamically, add them to `dynamicScripts` array.