# Changing index.html generation in Angular2

Tags: angular

I an deploying an Angular (2) App to a container that requires the NG2 JS to be loaded from a custom location.

Currently when i build my app, the index.html generates

```
<base href="/">
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
```

However i need it to generate something like:

```
<!--<base href="/">-->
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/custom/inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/custom/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/custom/styles.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/custom/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/custom/main.bundle.js"></script>
```

Is this possible? How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you use Angular CLI?

Comment: Try looking at `deployUrl`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the public path on angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43497322/how-to-set-the-public-path-on-angular-4)

Comment: Yes - I use Angular CLI

Answer (score 1):

In `.angular-cli.json`:

```
"deployUrl": "custom"
```

Comment: Can this be env based? It doesnt appear to be picked up if i put in an environments file.

Comment: You could put different values in different "apps" in your `angular-cli.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, deployUrl will work for your requirement but I will suggest you load the js file only when it is required(dynamically loading of js file).
Having js file in index.html is an easy way out & it should be used when that js file is necessary when the application is loading.Otherwise you should the other js when they are going to be used(in different componnets as per the requirement. )

Comment: Can you point me to how to do this with NG2? It seems NG2 is automatically injecting those includes into my index.html at build.

Comment: Also - can deployUrl be env specific (if deploy my NG App to my web platform, i need it to be /custom/xxx.bundle.js, however if i build it for a standalone (ex. mobile app) i'd want it to be /xxx.bundle.js

Comment: Yea. I have described the steps for dynamic loading the scripts in another thread.
Here is the link of that.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45294322/angularjs-2-4-loading-scripts/45299355#45299355

Comment: are these the "core" application JS files required to load the app (as produced by the ng build). How/why would i be able to lazy load them in? Other/supporting JS i can understand (ex. moment.js) but the core app JS seems like it MUST be loaded together?

Comment: Yes exactly, You should load core js in index file & all others js such as datatables, moment , bootBox js dynamically.